# Dependendant project's settings.gradle is not read

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an Android Project where I have multiple dependencies. The structure of my project is as follows:

- I have a library project called libA
- I have another library project called libB which is dependent on libA. I specify the dependency in a settings.gradle file that defines libA's project dir etc. I can independently build libB using this file.
- I have libC which depends on libB. I have a settings.gradle file here too and that defines the project dir. etc. for libB. When I run the build from here it gives me an error saying that libA was not found while building libB.

My question is this : Is the settings.gradle of libB not read at all when building libC? Is there a way to make it read that settings.gradle file?

Comment: No, one `settings.grade` per `Project`.

Comment: Are these projects inside each other, or completely separate? If they are one common project, they should share one `settings.gradle` file in the root project. If separate, one project cannot refer to another in the settings.gradle file, because they don't know how to find each other.

Comment: So how do you handle multiple android library projects that are needed by your library?

Comment: @Jolta These library projects all live at the same level but eventually needed by the application that lives in a higher level. The app builds well however I need this library for the unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a structure like this:

```
root
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  libA
    build.gradle
  libB
    build.gradle
  libC
    build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`

```
include ':libA' , ':libB'  , ':libC'
```

In `libB/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libA')
}
```

In `libC/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libB')
}
```

Comment: How do you build only libA in this case? Do you call gradle from the root?